Wifi is not connecting in Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS
In wifi settings no visible networks are being shown ,
But during the very initial stage of ubuntu installation network got connected but later its not connecting anymore .
Through ethernet wired connection is working 50 percent of the time , and other 50 percent of the times I had to turn off the machine and log in to windows uninstall all drivers and login to windows and turn off windows and turn on ubuntu .
This problem was there in 22.X version after I updated that version .
Any solutions for this .

That is the most common wifi issue. Make sure all updates are installed. Open Software & Updates, go to additional drivers. If possible/visible, enable the wifi driver. I recommend using a wired connection for this operation. Ubuntu can be very finicky when it comes to wifi drivers.

Trying "Upgrade Ubuntu kernel version" section in https://sypalo.com/how-to-upgrade-ubuntu.
I cannot vouch for the credibility of this solution to not compromise anything in your system.
